# Forward user requests from iFrame to parent via jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

If I have an iFrame and the user clicks a link/button/whatever that loads a different page in the iFrame, is there a way to intercept this and load the page in the parent window of the iFrame instead - using jquery (or in turn js)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

parant.location.href = "URL"

this will only work given both parent and iframe are from same domain

Comment: Thank, though not quite what I'm trying to do - from the parent window I'm trying to detect when the iframe changes page and then set the parent page to the same, rather than set the parent page from the iframe.

Comment: @James I think then you should use body tag of iframe on load call parent.location.href = window.location.href, this should work